# \DeclareFieldFormat command doesn't apply to phdthesis?

Tags: biblatex, formatting

I want to modify the format of title field in references entries of both article and phdthesis. It is odd that the modification only applies to article but not to phdthesis. See the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
        backend=biber,
        style=authoryear,
        %citestyle=authoryear,
        labelnumber=true,
        doi=true,
        url=true
        ]{biblatex}

        \makeatletter
        \input{numeric.bbx}
        \makeatother

        \DeclareFieldFormat[article,phdthesis]{title}{\textit{#1}}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
    @book{Foo,
        title={Book title1 whatever whatever whatever and tuff tuff
        and gong gong},
        author={Author1, AB and Author2, CD and Author3, EF},
        year= {Year1},
    }
    @book{Bar,
        title={Book title2},
        author={Author2, AB},
        year= {Year2},
    }
    @phdthesis{xyz,
        title={why declarefieldformat command doesn't apply to phdthesis},
        author={Author4, AB},
        year={2000},
    }
    @article{abc,
        author = {Author, New},
        year = {2014},
        title = {the format of article entry could be changed with D.},
        pages = {16--25},
        number = {9},
        journal = {Biblatex },
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{document}

text\footcite{Foo}, and text\footcite{Bar}
text\footcite{xyz}, and text\footcite{abc}

%\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `phdthesis` type is an alias to the `@thesis` type, since `biblatex` uses `@thesis` as the entry with the `type` field to specify the kind of thesis.

But the alias points to the actual type, and so can't be used in the `DeclareFieldFormat` command.  So instead use:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,thesis]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
```

Also, it's better to use `\emph` or `\mkbibemph` than `\textit` since it does italic correction and will also embed other `\emph` inside the title. (As noted in the comments, `\mkbibemph` behaves just like `\emph` so using `\emph` is fine.)

Comment: Of course it is even better to use `\mkbibemph{#1}` `:-)`, although I will admit that `\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibemph}{\emph}`...

Comment: @moewe Yes, I was going to do that but it seemed excessive. But I've updated the answer nonetheless. :)

Comment: Thank you. Excessive or not, the definitions in `biblatex.def` always use `\mkbibemph{#1}`, so I think it is a nice note to also keep doing it in one's modifications.