# biblatex: how to add exceptions to the main style?

Tags: biblatex

I am using the excellent template written by @moewe [biblatex: how to match the Journal of Finance bibliographic style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/379901/biblatex-how-to-match-the-journal-of-finance-bibliographic-style/379906#379906).

Unfortunately, I just noticed that *working papers* (`techreports`) need to have a little different style than regular articles.

Specifically, they should follow *all of* the conventions of regular articles (which are already specified in moewe's script) EXCEPT that for techreports the title that should NOT be in italic.

Here is an example (just use these two bib items with the template):

```
@article{johndoe_article,
  title={good morning everyone},
  author={Doe, John},
  journal={Journal of Stackoverlow},
  volume={13},
  number={1},
  pages={27--61},
  year={2014},
}


@techreport{johndoe_techreport,
title = {good morning everyone},
author = {Dow, John},
year = {2017},
institution = {Stackoverflow University},
type = {working paper},
}
```

gives:

[image]

As you can see

- the techreport's `title` is in italic, instead of being in normal
- the `title`, the `type` (working paper) and `institution` (stackoverflow university) are separated by a `.` instead of a comma `,`

How can I tweak the code to get these two little changes for `techreports`?
Thanks!!

Comment: Does this help? [\DeclareFieldFormat command doesn't apply to phdthesis?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/261108/2693) (In your case, you want simply `\DeclareFieldFormat[unpublished]{title}{#1}`.

Comment: thanks @AlanMunn but this does not seem to work. Actually, when you look at the example this is a `techreport` because the working paper has an institution field. I used your suggestion as `\DeclareFieldFormat[techreport]{title}{#1}` but the title still appears in italic... Do you have an idea?

Comment: Then please put the example into a minimal document that shows the problem, with some specific code, and a specific `.bib` item.

Comment: @AlanMunn edited my question completely. I hope everything is clear now. Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `techreport` entry type is an alias for the `report` type. So the correct field format command you need is:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[report]{title}{#1}
```

For the separation of the elements with commas you need to patch the bibliography driver for the `report` type.  I've used the `xpatch` package to do that. The `xpatch` package provides various commands specifically designed for changing `biblatex` macros, both of the `\bibmacro`  type and the `\BibliographyDriver` type (among others).  For this solution, I found where the bibliography driver for the `report` type was (in `standard.bbx`, the core code loaded by most `.bbx` files) and then used the `\xpatchbibdriver` command.

This command has the syntax:

```
\xpatchbibdriver{<driver name>}{<search code>}{<replace code}{<success>}{<failure>}
```

In this case, what needed to be done was to set the punctuation to `\addcomma\addspace`  before printing the `type` field and the `institution` field.

Here's a complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{johndoe_article,
  title={good morning everyone},
  author={Doe, John},
  journal={Journal of Stackoverlow},
  volume={13},
  number={1},
  pages={27--61},
  year={2014},
}


@techreport{johndoe_techreport,
title = {good morning everyone},
author = {Dow, John},
year = {2017},
institution = {Stackoverflow University},
type = {working paper},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, 
backend=biber, 
giveninits=true,
uniquelist = false, 
uniquename=init,
isbn=false, 
maxcitenames=3, 
maxbibnames=999,
doi=false,
url=false]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

%\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}


\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished,report]
  {title}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase*{#1}}


\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\setunit{\addcomma\space}}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitlecase}{#1}

\renewbibmacro*{journal}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{journaltitle}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{journalsubtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[journaltitle]{%
       \printfield[journaltitlecase]{journaltitle}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[journaltitlecase]{journalsubtitle}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}


\xpatchbibdriver{report}{\newunit\newblock\printfield{type}}
    {\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}\newblock\printfield{type}}{}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{report}{\newunit\newblock\usebibmacro{institution+location+date}}
    {\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}\newblock\usebibmacro{institution+location+date}}{}{}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}% volume of a journal

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\begin{document}
\textcite{johndoe_article,johndoe_techreport}


\printbibliography
\end{document}

[![output of code][1]][1]
```

Comment: thanks !! that fixes the italic, but the `title`, the `type` (working paper) and `institution` are still separated by a `.` instead of being separated by a comma `,`. Can we change that easily as well?

Comment: maybe by having the `report` type inheriting these features from the regular `article` type? Thanks again!!

Comment: ? are you still there?

Comment: @Noobie I've updated the answer.

Comment: amazing thanks again. This bibtex syntax, while powerful, is a bit difficult to grasp. Maybe could you add a few comments to explain what's going on with your `xpatch` line? that would help me and other learn new `biblatex` skills... :D

Comment: @Noobie The syntax itself is not so much the problem as much as knowing where to look to find the things to change. There's a lot of code, and it distributed among a few different files.  I don't have time to answer this now. But I actually think it would be a worthwhile question to ask on its own (something like "How do I know where to find things I can change in `biblatex` or something). You could link it to this question. There are quite a few extremely good `biblatex` users around who would probably have better answers than I could give to that question.

Comment: @Noobie I've added some more explanation of what I did, but the general question would be a really useful one to have.